# json jquery - displaying html as text instead of html

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am using jQuery to call a php page (via ajax) that goes to my server to grab some data.  The  data is then encoded to json and returned to the page.  I am then parsing the json with jQuery.  I am having a problem displaying html items that are getting returned.  In the json object the piece of data in question is a value to a "description" key.  The json gets returned as below:

```
{ "description" : "Check the Wiki article to see what states require Two-Party Notification. (&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://intranet.clickmotive.com/Wiki/Call%20Recording%20-%20Two%20Party%20Notification%20States.ashx&amp;quot; target=&amp;quot;_blank&amp;quot;&amp;gt;wiki link&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;)" }
```

Then i use a simple function that i found on here to decode the html.  Then function i'm using is this (i pass the value of the above key through to this function):

```
function htmlDecode(value){
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

This decodes the text it to be as follows:

```
Check the Wiki article to see what states require Two-Party Notification. (<a href="http://intranet.clickmotive.com/Wiki/Call%20Recording%20-%20Two%20Party%20Notification%20States.ashx" target="_blank">wiki link</a>)
```

This is how i am adding it to the page: (where the 'description' variable is being set from the json data)

```
$("#description").append(htmlDecode(description));
```

My problem is that it is displaying the full html as text and not as html.  So, there is no link being created.  What is my problem with this code?  I must be missing something.  Let me know if you have any questions!  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it working fine by only using `$("#description").append(description);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is double [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php) encoded. So there are two ways to solve this problem:

### jQuery

The thing what you've done is almost good:

```
function htmlDecode(value){
    return $('<div/>').html($('<div/>').html(value).text()).text();
}
```

Or simply call your `htmlDecode()` method twice as [@Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818453/#answer-7818732) mentioned.

```
htmlDecode(htmlDecode(description));
```

### JsonML

I think it would be a better idea to use [JsonML](http://jsonml.org/) instead of simple JSON for this.

JsonML is a JSON encoding of an XML document (or node), so actually it would fit better for your problem.

I wrote a JsonML jQuery plugin, which you can fetch form [github](https://github.com/raszi/jQuery-JsonML). You'll need a PHP JsonML encoder as well, which is easy to write, and I think there should be available implementations as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Your first suggestion worked like a charm.  I thought that may be the problem.  I'll look in to the JsonML stuff...sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your source json data has been encoded twice so all your ampersands are escaped.

Replace your call with:

```
htmlDecode(htmlDecode(description))
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using Jquery Templates then in the template you can simply add {{html expression }}

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

Thanks